# Filter out groups that only contains certain information - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter out participant within a family number which does not contain at least one parent and one child, and the family number must have at least two participants i.e. in this case I'd want to remove family_number 2.

```
Participant   Family_number    Family_member
A             1                Child
B             1                Parent
C             2                Child
D             2                Child
E             3                Parent
F             3                Child
G             3                Child
```

As I want to use dplyr, I've tried using group_by() and filter() however I either end up with no data or get an error.

Any tips?

Thanks,

Julia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example?

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% group_by(Family_number) %>% 
  filter(sum(Family_member == "Parent") >= 1 & sum(Family_member == "Child") >= 1)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Family_number [2]
  Participant Family_number Family_member
  <fct>               <dbl> <fct>        
1 A                    1.00 Child        
2 B                    1.00 Parent       
3 E                    3.00 Parent       
4 F                    3.00 Child        
5 G                    3.00 Child
```

Comment: You could also use the `dplyr::n()` function within `filter` instead of `length` of one of the vectors. Using `n()` might be more expressive.

Comment: isn't it `length` or `n` redundant anyway? if it has a child and a parent then ergo it has at least 2 members?